# A simple webserver that serves HTML files

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, html, lightweight

I am having a bunch of HTML files getting generated everytime when I run a periodic task in my server. All I want to do is to display the index.html through a webserver. All the links in the index file are linked within that directory. How to do this efficiently. I don't want the server to be robust. I want to hit something like this at the end

```
http://myservername:1234/index.html
```

Comment: `apt-get install apache` then write your files to /var/www/apache2-default/, Apache might not be the most performance efficient on high load sites, but it'll happily sit there in the background using pretty much zero memory and CPU, and it's really simple to install

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered installing [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)? It sounds pretty much like what you need.

Also look at the [package details for Ubuntu and the article on Softpedia](http://bitly.com/p5LAsS). Possibly ignoring the PHP and MySQL references?

**Edit**: after installing the web server, do what RainyRat has suggested ;)

Comment: Sexy!! Thank you very much. I followed this link in particular to have a server up and running in 2 minutes.
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/TutorialConfiguration

Answer (score 5):

Just get your periodic task to output the HTML files into a specific directory, then set that directory as your webserver's document root and make sure that the default document is set to (or at least includes) index.html.  That way, when your task runs the "site" will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For simple static content to be viewed locally, just use the `file://` pseudo-protocol, supported by almost every web browser.

`file:///home/user/foo_generated_html/index.html`